# MySQL - GROUP multiple rows while retaining differences

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, max

I have a series of complicated MySQL select queries / joins that produce results similar to this:

```
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
| id | company | city     | province | manager_email | staff_email   |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
| 1  | aaa     | toronto  | ON       | john@aaa.com  |               |
| 1  | aaa     | toronto  | ON       |               | smith@aaa.com |
| 2  | bbb     | sudbury  | ON       | john@bbb.com  |               |
| 3  | ccc     | hamilton | ON       | john@ccc.com  |               |
| 3  | ccc     | hamilton | ON       |               | smith@ccc.com |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
```

- most "companies" have two rows, which are identical other than the emails
- `manager_email` and `staff_email` will never appear in the same row
- there are some cases where a "company" will only have one row

Is there a `GROUP BY` or a similar statement that I can use to group all of these duplicate rows, while retaining both emails? e.g.

```
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
| id | company | city     | province | manager_email | staff_email   |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
| 1  | aaa     | toronto  | ON       | john@aaa.com  | smith@aaa.com |
| 2  | bbb     | sudbury  | ON       | john@bbb.com  |               |
| 3  | ccc     | hamilton | ON       | john@ccc.com  | smith@ccc.com |
|----|---------|----------|----------|---------------|---------------|
```

I'm willing to share more details if needed, but at this point I think it'll just add confusion.

Comment: This needs to work with MySQL 5.6 by the way.

Comment: *"I'm willing to share more details if needed, but at this point I think it'll just add confusion."* Are there indexes on the table ?? `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`

Comment: @RaymondNijland not in the rows I'm selecting, but there are unique indexes I could be grabbing. This is just for my personal data collection from a specific database.

Comment: Also, the data your seeing is the result of 5 or 6 `INNER JOINS` across multiple tables, if that helps...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that most aggregate functions ignore `null`:

```
select 
    id, 
    company, 
    city, 
    province, 
    max(manager_email) manager_email, 
    max(staff_email) staff_email
from mytable
group by id, company, city, province
```

Comment: It could very well be due to how my queries are structured, but this is creating a `NULL` `staff_email` in most rows. Any ideas?

Comment: when i read your comment i am pretty sure you don't understood this query or your own data for that matter... @shaneparsons  this query does give the [expected results](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fR2GkjD9T3n7XXGVo8yeTL/0) you where looking for in the question..

Comment: *"It could very well be due to how my queries are structured, but this is creating a NULL staff_email in most rows."* @shaneparsons  If you think this query is flawed you need to make a better example which better suited your your real live data.. But pretty sure it simply because those `staff_email` value in those records is simply `NULL` to begin with, did you check it ?

Comment: Yeah, there's a lot I'm doing wrong in my hacky query, which is essentially the result of me not knowing how to do this... I'll add some more details to the question to help clarify.

Comment: *"I'll add some more details to the question to help clarify"*  Better to write a complete new question with all the information in it more or less the requirement of Stackoverflow as the complete question changes now ..  But you might want you make a reference to this question to prevent vote closes for question duplication

Comment: @RaymondNijland I've created [a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959573/mysql-joining-the-same-table-twice-but-grabbing-different-results) with more detail on my complicated situation... I don't know if you or anybody will be able to help me, but I'd appreciate if you checked it out!

Comment: This essentially ended up being the answer after all... I just had to learn how to wrap my `CASE` statements with `max()`. Cheers!

Comment: Never too late for a spot of house-keeping